# how to pass correctly a module in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, module, architecture

app.js --------------

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const utils = require("./config/utils");
const app = express();

utils.initializeDb(mongoose);
app.listen(3000);
```

config/utils.js

```
module.exports = (mongoose) => {
  initializeDb: async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(
      process.env.MONGO_URI,
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Mongoose connection successfuly started");
      }
    );
  };
};
```

The error in the terminal/console is: TypeError: utils.initializeDb is not a function.

I'm digging into optimization, encapsulation, to clean more my code passing modules through functions and etc. and I tried this thing but it give me this error... I would like to know the error that is happening in the code and also some tips on how to optimize this code. Thank you :)

Comment: `utils` is a function. Why not remove that and only export an object? And also put the `mongoose` parameter into the `initializeDb` function definition.

Comment: `utils.initializeDb(mongoose)` should be `utils(mongoose).initializeDb()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below method :

app.js

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const initializeDb = require("./config/utils");
    const app = express();

    initializeDb(mongoose);
    app.listen(3000);
```

config/utils.js

```
module.exports = {
  initializeDb: async (mongoose) => {
    await mongoose.connect(
      process.env.MONGO_URI,
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Mongoose connection successfuly started");
      }
    );
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks to you now I understand where it was the problem before, but talking about asynchronous concepts and optimization of the code, in app.js I'm deconstructing, so it's: const { initializeDb } = require('./config/utils'). When do I call this function should I use an async IIFE or promises or simply initializeDb(mongoose) ?